# I need to get my pictures from the iPad to my PC

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization, windows

I got my iPad in february, and got it syncing with my PC. That transfered all my music and pictures onto my iPad (Nice). But then my hard drive on my PC said goodbye and didn't want to work any more.

So all of my pictures are gone, I just got a baby girl and we had taken pictures of her in the hospital and everything (And YES, I didn't make a back up of my pictures with all the latest pictures).

In my iPad, the pictures are located in albums, but when I connect my iPad to the PC, it will only transfer 4 pictures (those located in the file: archived pictures). I have over 3000 pictures on my iPad, and now this is the only place I have the latest pics.

Is there anything I can do? Or is this as a lost case?

Comment: Just a simple warning if you're paranoid: DO NOT CONNECT IT TO ITUNES, A SIMPLE SYNC MAY GET RID OF IT

Answer (score 2):

Create an account in [**Dropbox**](http://db.tt/tFjge6n) (this is a referral link, it will give both of us 250 Mb of free storage).

Install the free [**Dropbox app**](http://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/dropbox/id327630330?mt=8) on your iPad.

Use the Dropbox bulk uploader to add the pictures on your iPad to your Dropbox account.

Install the Dropbox app (found on http://www.dropbox.com) on your computer.

It will download the pictures you added to your dropbox account on your computer.

The free Dropbox account is 2Gb (2.25 if you used my link). So you might need to repeat this operation multiple times (copy the file from the Dropbox folder to another folder and delete the files on your Dropbox folder)

Comment: just a note: don't forget to change the settings for image quality to the best, as this is not the default.

Answer (score 0):

The following app allows you to transfer photos from the iPad onto a PC (or Mac/iPhone) and works quite well:

http://phototransferapp.com/